# is this compound or compound complex, classifying clauses

Tags: grammar

Please, i don't know why this sentence perplexes me.

Come quick big brothers and stay with me for my house is big and sturdy.

I couldn't classify the clauses hence I couldn't classify the sentence.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Comma where? After "and", or after "me"? It's kind of a style issue, not grammar. From the Grammar tag: " Also do not use this for punctuation or spelling (orthography); those are not about grammar, and they have their own tags."

Comment: "Come quick, big brothers, and stay with me, for my house is big and sturdy."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Come quick and stay with me" is the basic sentence. "Big brothers" is a noun phrase that you're using to say whom you're addressing. "For" is used to mean "because" in this case, so "for my house is big and sturdy" is a dependent clause explaining the reason why you're telling them to stay with you.